# The same code is not working in a different activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, touch-event

I have this code, supposed to catch the swipe events in one of my activities:

```
private float x1,x2;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x1 = event.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            x2 = event.getX();
            float deltaX = x2 - x1;

            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
            {
                // Left to Right swipe action
                if (x2 > x1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right swipe [Previous]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter, R.anim.animation_leave);

                }

                // Right to left swipe action
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Right to Left swipe [Next]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                // TO DO
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Now I just moved the same **working** code in another activity and it is not showing the toast message when I swipe left or right. What can be causing the issue? I know that I'm missing something really small, but I can not spot it at the momment.

EDIT the non working activity:

```
public class BulgarianSayings extends Activity {

    private float x1,x2;
    static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bulgarian_sayings);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bulgarian_sayings, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bulgarian_sayings, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x1 = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x2 = event.getX();
                float deltaX = x2 - x1;

                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                {
                    // Left to Right swipe action
                    if (x2 > x1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right swipe [Previous]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                        this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter, R.anim.animation_leave);

                    }

                    // Right to left swipe action
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Right to Left swipe [Next]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    // consider as something else - a screen tap for example
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: show toast else part of if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE).

Comment: @DivyangMetalia nothing happens... Like the event is never fired.

Comment: i try same code in my both activity its work.

paste your both activity that you run.

Comment: Looks like there isn't any problem in this code (cause it worked in original one). I suggest to look at different part of activity. Maybe variables you declare before oncreat, item orders and ids in xml, etc.

Comment: @DivyangMetalia it is a lot of code I pasted only the non working activity

Comment: Consider using `SimpleGestureListener` and its `onFling()` to detect swipes. Working with raw `MotionEvent`s properly is often unnecessarily complex.

Comment: you are not appending ontouchlistener on any views. check your original activity (which this code is working on that), you will see an ontouchlistener or even extending ontouchlistener in top of activity (instead of `public class BulgarianSayings extends Activity`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should append the onTouchListener on a view to make it work.

For example If you want to implementing this on whole view You could do this:

```
// First make an id for your View (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.) 
// and then decaler it as a view.
View view = findViewById(R.id.rellayout); 

// then append onTouchListener on it
view.setOnTouchListener(Your OnTouchListener Class or Method);
```

Other way is to work like this in top of activity:

```
public class BulgarianSayings extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

//Your Other parts
```